# How to display JSON data seperated correctly in UITableview cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

I've been able to get data from a local JSON file to display in a tableview

**but it's displaying like this:**

.......................cell1...............................

Biscuits

3 cups All-purpose Flour

2 Tablespoons Baking Powder

1/2 teaspoon Salt

.......................cell2...............................

12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)

1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)

......................................................

**And I need it to display each ingredient separated into its own cell like this:**

.......................cell1...............................

Biscuits

.......................cell2...............................

3 cups All-purpose Flour

.......................cell3...............................

2 Tablespoons Baking Powder

.......................cell4...............................

1/2 teaspoon Salt

.......................cell5...............................

12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)

.......................cell6...............................

1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)

...........................................................

**What code would I need to display the data correctly?  Heres my current code:**

```
   /////////locations.json/////////////////////////////
    {
      "locations": [

    { "ingredients" : "Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking Powder\n1/2 teaspoon Salt\nShortened for example” },

    { "ingredients" : "12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)\n1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)\nShortened for example” },  
    //many more records.  only included 2 for example                            
      ]
    }
    /////////Location.h/////////////////////////////////////////
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Location : NSObject

    - (id)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary;

    @property (readonly) NSString *ingredients;

    @end


    ////////Location.m////////////////////////////////////
    #import "Location.h"

    @implementation Location

    // Init the object with information from a dictionary
    - (id)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary {
    if(self = [self init]) {
        // Assign all properties with keyed values from the dictionary

        _ingredients = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
    }
    return self;
    }
    @end


    ////////JSONLoader.h////////////////////////////////////
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface JSONLoader : NSObject

    // Return an array of Location objects from the json file at location given by url
    - (NSArray *)locationsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url;
    @end


    ////////JSONLoader.m////////////////////////////////////
    #import "JSONLoader.h"
    #import "Location.h"

    @implementation JSONLoader

    - (NSArray *)locationsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response  error:nil];

    // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"];
    // Iterate through the array of dictionaries
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        // Create a new Location object for each one and initialize it with information in the dictionary
        Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
        // Add the Location object to the array
        [locations addObject:location];
    }

    // Return the array of Location objects
    return locations;
}
@end

////////TableViewController.h////////////////////////////////////
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Location.h"

@interface FilterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) Location *location;

@end


////////TableViewController.m////////////////////////////////////
#import "FilterViewController.h"
#import "LocationsViewController.h"
#import "Location.h"
#import "JSONLoader.h"

@implementation FilterViewController {
    NSArray *_locations;   
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
    JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"locations" withExtension:@"json"];

    // Load the data on a background queue...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        _locations = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];
        // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        });
}
// Just before showing the LocationDetailViewController, set the selected Location object
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    LocationsViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    vc.location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FilterCell"];

    Location *location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = location.ingredients;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredientsicon3232.png"];
    return cell;   
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_locations count];
}
@end
```

**Note:  I'm unable to change the JSON data format as it's from an outside source and there's a lot more "ingredients" keys than I posted in the example.**

Comment: what i get from your code is that you are using wrong array for the number of section. if you are setting your cell.textlabel.text with "location" array objects then use that also for your number of section. and then set the number of rows in section to 1.

Comment: @roozbehmo Thanks for sharing your suggestion.  Would you be able to provide this suggestion in code?  I don't see number of section in my code and trying to understand.  Still very new to this and trying to learn.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Some sample code for you to get a working.

```
// JSONLoader.m 

- (NSArray *)locationsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
    // Existing code .......

    // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"];
    // Iterate through the array of dictionaries
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
        NSArray *brokenIntoParts = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        for (NSString *ingredient in brokenIntoParts) {
            [locations addObject:ingredient];
        }
    }

    // Return the array of Location objects
    return locations;
}

// FilterViewController.m

#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FilterCell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredientsicon3232.png"];
    return cell;   
}
```

**Original:**

Your code looks fine, actually just change your data,

```
{
  "locations": [ { "ingredients" : "Biscuits"}, 
                 { "ingredients" : "3 cups All-purpose Flour"},
                 { "ingredients" : "Tablespoons Baking Powder"}
.
.
.                                                               
]}
```

This should solve your problem, basically you want key:value of "keyword":ingredient, please comment if it does not, good luck.

Comment: @ JingJingTao I'm unable to change the data format as it's from an outside source and there's a lot more "ingredients" keys than I posted in the example.

Comment: :p, I thought you might say that, you could try separate the value based on the new line escape character.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a very new to this.  Would you be able to provide a code example to demonstrate how that would work?

Comment: No worries, NSArray *brokenByLines = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"], this does assume that there are new line characters in the source

Comment: I've tried that method previously as well, but I have to be doing something wrong because I get the error ! No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'componentsSeperatedByString:'.  Maybe I'm putting that code in the wrong place?  I added NSArray *brokenByLines = [_locations componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; in my tableviewcontroller under: Location *location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: You get that error because you pass "location" which is an array, you should pass 'locations.ingredients'. We can continue this in chat, if that's more helpful, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Comment: Tried chat, but I don't have enough rep points yet.  Just signed up yesterday.  I did your suggestion, then  did what I thought was the next step and changed cell.textLabel to cell.textLabel.text = brokenByLines; but I get the error message ! Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString*_Nullable' from 'NSArray*'.  Not sure what i'm doing wrong, but I surely appreciate your help!  Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah my bad on the chat thing, you need to use an index of the array, e.g. [brokenByLines objectForIndex:indexPath.row], although you will probably need the tableview to use brokenByLines.count as the number of rows and brokenByLines has to contain all the values. I do feel my suggestions are dirtying your solution abit, although I guess let's get it to work and then refactor :D

Comment: I've been trying to fix for days so not worried about it being dirty.  Where do I put [brokenByLines objectForIndex:indexPath.row]?  Do I add that to cell.textLabel.text?

Comment: Yep, you want to assign the string value in the brokenByLines array to your cell.

Comment: Ok, I did     cell.textLabel.text = [brokenByLines objectForIndex:indexPath.row];   and get error   !No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'ObjectForIndex:'.  What do you think i'm missing?

Comment: Sorry I meant 'objectAtIndex', I'm off for the next few hours, let me know how it goes, I'll reply when I can.

Comment: That fixed the error, but the app crashes now.  How would I use brokenByLines.count as the number of rows and make sure brokenByLines contain all the values as you previously suggested?  Thanks again for your help!  Making progress!

Comment: Let's try this, change your 'locationsFromJSONFile' method, in the loop create a NSString from [dict objectForKey:@"ingredients"], then use that string to create 'brokenByLines' then loop through 'brokenByLines' and add component as a string each to locations. This means we are not using your Location object at the moment and so in your viewcontroller for the 'cellForIndexPath' method do, 'cell.textLabel.text = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];'

Comment: Your suggestion makes since, but I'm having a hard time translating it into the correct code.  Could you provide a code example of what you suggest?

Comment: Awesome!  That's exactly what I needed and it works perfectly.  Thanks again for all your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

This code extracts the `ingredients` from the dictionary using the key-value coding method `valueForKey` and converts the newline separated strings to an array.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary =  @{@"locations" : @[@{ @"ingredients" : @"Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking Powder\n1/2 teaspoon Salt\nShortened for example" },
                                                   @{ @"ingredients" : @"12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)\n1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)\nShortened for example" }]};


NSArray* locations = jsonDictionary[@"locations"];
NSMutableArray *ingredients = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *jsonIngredients = [locations valueForKey:@"ingredients"];
for (NSString *ingredient in jsonIngredients) {
    [ingredients addObjectsFromArray:[ingredient componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", ingredients);
```

The result `ingredients` can be used directly as the data source array.

**Edit:**

**Your model class `Location` is actually incompatible with the JSON data format**

To try the code you have to assign the result `ingredients` to your data source array `_locations`

```
_locations = ingredients;
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` replace the lines

```
Location *location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = location.ingredients;
```

with

```
NSString *ingredient = _locations[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = ingredient;
```

PS: If you are also responsible for the JSON on the server side consider to use a more convenient data format.

Comment: I've been trying to adapt your suggestion into my code for the last few hours, but can't get the app to stop crashing with countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count message.  Here's the code I'm trying to use based on your answer:

Comment: Location *location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    //NSArray* locations = [_location valueForKey: @"locations"];
    NSMutableArray *ingredients = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *jsonIngredients = [location valueForKey:@"ingredients"];
    for (NSString *ingredient in jsonIngredients) {
        [ingredients addObjectsFromArray:[ingredient componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
    }
   NSLog(@"%@", ingredients);
    cell.textLabel.text = [ingredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried your suggestions various different ways over the last few hours.  I can see the full ingredients array in the console, but I get either errors or crashes no matter what I try.  The crash errors I would get were either Location is equal to string, Location class not key value compliant for key ingredients, or countbyenumerating errors.   With your modified code suggestions, I was able to get the array results back into the tableview at one point, but the tableview displayed data the same as it did in the original question (each key/values combined in 1 cell) with below code

Comment: Modified JSONLoader with: NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"];
    NSMutableArray *ingredients = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *jsonIngredients = [array valueForKey:@"ingredients"];
    for (NSString *ingredient in jsonIngredients) {
        [ingredients addObjectsFromArray:[ingredient componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
    } NSLog(@"%@", ingredients); //and modified controller with: NSString *ingredient = _locations[indexPath.row]; cell.textLabel.text = [ingredient valueForKey:@"ingredients"]; cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //Why will it not seperate?